# Windows batch script: substring calculation

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a situation like this. I have a list of urls in a file.

`SET str1="http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt"`

In the above string `http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3` is constant in all the urls. 
I need to extract the rest of the path in each url.

I mean, i need to get the final string from the above url is `/dir4/dir5/file1.txt`

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the `%var:~start,end%` notation. For example, if you run this:

```
@SET str1="http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt"
@ECHO %str1:~37,-1%
```

It will print `/dir4/dir5/file1.txt`.

Comment: In fact you should say "%var:~start,length% notation"

Comment: @hoang: Clearly `-1` is not a length. If you use a positive number it's a length, but the OP doesn't want to specify a length (because the substring is variable length). Using a negative number specifies an ending position, which is what is called for here because the OP wants the substring ending right before the ending quote.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed the point that a negative number is a position from the end.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use the [`%variable:str_to_delete=%`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) syntax to delete a character string from the variable. This way you don't have to rely on the character positions within the string.

Example code:

```
@echo off
set str1="http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file1.txt"

:: remove the common part of the path
set str2=%str1:http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3=%
:: remove the quotes
set str2=%str2:"=%

echo.%str2%
```

Output:

```
/dir4/dir5/file1.txt
```