# MS-DOS batch script: substring from url

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have an other question.

I have an url like this

`@SET var1="http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file.txt"`.

In this url I need to get `"http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/"` path.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch script: substring calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275233/windows-batch-script-substring-calculation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var1="http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file.txt"

set var2=%var1%

:loop
if "!var2:~-2,1!"=="/" goto endloop
set var2="%var2:~1,-2%"
goto loop

:endloop
echo.%var2%
```

It removes characters from the end of the path until `/` is reached.